# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff

Tags: android

I get this error report that doesn't show where it is coming from in the app. It seems to be external. Is there anything I can do about it?

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:87)
at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java)
at miui.util.UiUtils.getColor(UiUtils.java:127)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView$Injector.checkTextColor(ListMenuItemView.java:104)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.setCheckable(ListMenuItemView.java)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.initialize(ListMenuItemView.java)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.getView(ListMenuPresenter.java)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

edit: Figured out its external and not from my app. My question now is what can I do about it to stop people giving me 1 star?

Comment: Check `miui.util.UiUtils.getColor(UiUtils.java:127)`

Comment: Issue with the library. See [this](http://yatse.leetzone.org/redmine/boards/2/topics/1512)

Comment: Somebody is passing -1 into `getColor()`, perhaps as a flawed default value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xiaomi devices using miui. It seems like the issue lies inside miui. But I've found a workaround:

The problem disappeared for me when switching to Material Design using the [`appcompat-v7`](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) library. Previously the app theme was based on `@android:style/Theme.Holo`, now it is inheriting from `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` and it works.

If you don't want to use Material Design, maybe this will give you some clue (not verified):
http://en.miui.com/thread-13394-1-1.html

I cannot confirm it, but there is someone guessing:

> I think, the problem lied on, miui can't handle menu with property android:checkable="true"